# How to turn /filename.php into /filename/

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I can't seem to google this. I'm trying to build my website but I wish to specify the files (ie /filename.php) and turn them into /filename/ in the url and links. I'm not sure if this is url rewrite or file redirect or whatever? Is there a framework I can use for this?

Comment: use .htaccess for url rewriting and SEO friendly urls

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: @David I think Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The line with !-d checks that it's not a directory, the line with -f checks that the requested file is a .php file.

```
Current URL: www.example.com/something.php 
Output  URL:www.example.com/something/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something that's usually done through the web server, so the answer depends on whether you're using Apache, Nginx, or something else. Here's how I do it with Nginx.

I typically have a directory in my site root called `controllers`. All of the files in `controllers` correspond to URL paths. For example:

```
/controllers/home.php ---> http://example.com/home
/controllers/about.php ---> http://example.com/about
/controllers/contact.php ---> http://example.com/contact
```

Then I use the web server (Nginx) to direct the traffic (which is what it's built to do). So if Nginx gets a request for `http://example.com/home`, then it looks in the `controllers` directory for a file called `home.php`. If the file exists, then Nginx serves it up. If the file doesn't exist, then Nginx serves up some fallback page. Here's what the Nginx configuration looks like:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  root /srv/example;
  index index.php;

  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controllers$uri.php?$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table for slug .slug are associated with file name and  directory .

structure of slug table should be slugId | slug |file name | path

all request go to your Url class that actually fetch file name according to slug-name() that

show on on url . your site htaccess should move all request in index . on index you call the

function of urls call and require value according to slug .